# In webapi 2 can i use memory cache for 2 days in application cache memory?

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, memorycache

I have found memory cache will be available for 20 minutes in the application.
If you use MemoryCache.Default then your cache lives as long as your application pool lives. (Just to remind you that default application pool idle time-out is 20 minutes which is less than 1 hour.)
**library** : `using System.Runtime.Caching;`
Which is the best cache mechanism in the webapi layer for 48 hours caching.

Comment: As you've pointed out, anything that relies on the application is at the mercy of the life of the application. If you have the resources you could use something like Redis which wouldn't be affected or perhaps looking at something primitive like caching to a file.  I guess it all depends on the use case.

Comment: You've probably ruled this out as an option already but you could always change the IIS AppPool setting (under Advanced) for the Idle Timeout. However, would agree with @PhilCooper re persisting.